# Custom markdown tag

Tags: regex, markdown

I'm using [dflydev's markdown](https://github.com/dflydev/dflydev-markdown/blob/master/src/dflydev/markdown/MarkdownExtraParser.php) which is based on [michelf's project](http://michelf.ca/projects/php-markdown) to transform Markdown into HTML.

My site is RTL by default and I'd like to add a custom tag to allow left-aligning paragraphs,
something like:

```
regular text, right aligned.

<- some text that will be aligned to the left

<--
fenced text that will be aligned to the left
<--
```

I'm trying to build the regex pattern to catch those blocks:

- For `<- ...` I have: `/^<- ([^\n]+)/`
- For the fenced block I couldn't get a working pattern

I'd like to get help on the fenced block regex and on improving the one-line regex I already have.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This would match your second group:

```
^<--.*?<--$
```

For your first group I would use something like this instead:

```
^<-[^-][^\r\n]*?$
```

Comment: It matches the block content correctly, but I need to replace the whole block `<-- ... <--` with the HTML `<span>...</span>` and the matches don't include the tags `<--`

Comment: @tamir checkout [my response](http://stackoverflow.com/a/14031874/1006989), I updated it to include the tags

Answer (score 0):

For your first case you can use

```
/^<-(.*?)$/
```

and get the **first group**.

For the second case use

```
/^<--(.*?)<--$/
```

and get the **first group**.